# Should you downvote an answer that solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, voting, wrong-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should you downvote an answer that “works” because it is not strictly “correct”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/should-you-downvote-an-answer-that-works-because-it-is-not-strictly-correct)

This is slightly related to a similar question I found on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/should-you-downvote-an-answer-that-works-because-it-is-not-strictly-correct), but is more specific in the following capacity:

1. Question X is asked by Person A.
2. A definitive answer is provided for X. It is based upon fact--no opinion is involved.
3. Another Person (B) provides answer Y--it is a **workaround**, completely sidestepping the question, but *accurately solves the person's problem*.
4. Person A likes the workaround, accepts the answer, and dismisses the fact-based answer, even when it addresses the original question.

For example:

> Q: How do I write a function with optional parameters?
>
> Answer X: void foo(...);
>
> Answer Y: I prefer to use named arguments with default values instead!
>   -> void foo(int a=0);

While answer Y may be a best practice, and perhaps recommended by a number of individuals...it does not answer the original question, which has a factual answer (that was supplied).

So, what is the best way to resolve this? Comments? Upvotes/Downvotes? More?

Comment: Upvote what you like.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101714/if-i-solve-someones-problem-instead-of-answering-their-question-should-i-post-a

Answer (score 6):

It's a personal choice.

If it's a good answer that looks like it will help somebody, then I'll upvote it.

If it's just a rant on proper technique, then I won't.

I would never downvote a good answer.